# swap sequences of different length between two vectors in c++

Tags: c++, stl, vector, range, swap

Say you have two integer vectors:

[image]

[image]

I would like to define a function that allows me to swap a range of elements among the two vectors passing start index and lenght of the two sequences as arguments.

For instance: [image] where [image] and [image] are vectors and the numbers passed as arguments represents starting index and lenght of the sequences.

In this case I should get as autput

v1 = 1,2,       **13,14,15**   ,5,6,7,8,9

v2 = 10,11,12,  **3,4**        ,16,17,18

the signature of the function I defined as an example is not a constraint, if you think there is a better way it is ok

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that all the regular STL algorithms fall short of what you want to do exactly:

`std::swap_ranges` would be almost there, but it requires that you swap equally long ranges
`std::rotate` would also not be bad, but it requires that the end point of one range equals the begin point of the second range.

```
// pseudo-splice on vector
v1.insert(v1.begin() + 2 + 2, v2.begin() + 3, v2.begin() + 3 + 3);
v2.erase(v2.begin() + 3, v2.begin() + 3 + 3);

// pseudo-splice on vector
v2.insert(v2.begin() + 3, v1.begin() + 2, v1.begin() + 2 + 2);
v1.erase(v1.begin() + 2, v1.begin() + 2 + 2);
```

You can of course easily abstract this into a function template that takes arbitrary iterator boundaries for your two ranges.

**Edit** based on David's comment, you can do some optimization to avoid needless resizing

```
// compute smallest range here, in this case it's the v1 part
std::swap_ranges(v1.begin() + 2, v1.begin() + 2 + 2, v2.begin() + 3);

// now handle the remaining part of the longest range, in this case it's element v2 + 3 + 2
std::insert(v1.begin() + 2 + 2, v2.begin() + 3 + 2);
std::erase(v2.begin() + 3 + 2);
```

**Update**: it would be easier if you used `std::list` since then you could use `splice` (I rearranged the `insert` / `erase` part there to mimic the code below)

```
v1.splice(v1.begin() + 2 + 2, v2, v2.begin() + 3, v2.begin() + 3 + 3);
v2.splice(v2.begin() + 3, v1, v1.begin() + 2, v1.begin() + 2 + 2);
```

Comment: +1 because it works. It can be improved to avoid some of the resizing of the vectors (say swap the `min(length1,length2)` first elements and then insert/remove the remainder), but I am a bit lazy to code that now.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Tnx, it would be nice if there was an STL splice on vector.

Answer (score 1):

I think this shouldn't raise any difficulties besides the fact that you will have to re-assign the vectors if Length1 != Length2.

```
 swap_elements(v1, start1, length1, v2, start2, length2){
      if(length1 != length2){
        //alloc mem for both of the arrays
        //copy the unmodified portions of the original arrays into the new arrays
      }

      //swap the elements
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing it in place with insert and erase has worse running time than the code below because each time insert and erase are called the other elements of the vector have to be moved accordingly in memory, and allocate new memory block, move vector elements to new memory block, if necessary. To avoid resizing and memory issues, it might be preferable to just create two new vector at the very beginning.

```
swap_elements(vector<int> &v1, int s1, int l1, vector<int> &v2, int s2, int l2){
    vector<int> nv1(v1.begin(),v1.begin()+s1);
    vector<int> nv2(v2.begin(),v2.begin()+s2);
    for(int i=0;i<l2;i++)
      nv1.push_back(v2[s2+i]);
    for(int i=0;i<l1;i++)
      nv2.push_back(v1[s1+i]);
    for(int i=s1+l1+1;i<v1.size();i++)
      nv1.push_back(v1[i]);
    for(int i=s2+l2+1;i<v2.size();i++)
      nv2.push_back(v2[i]);
    v1.clear();
    v2.clear();
    v1=nv1;
    v2=nv2;
}
```